# Deployment of Picklist values of which "API" names have been changed

Tags: picklist

I have changed "API" names of few picklist values for following fields in an "Account" object.
Specialty
Specialty 2
Tendency
Tendency 2

But not able to deploy these picklist values to other sandboxes due to duplicate label error, even though there are no duplicate labels or values.
as shown in below image.
[image]
Kindly help me in deploying these picklist values.

Comment: A rename is equivalent to add (new) and delete (old). However, deleting the old values is not automatically part of what will be deployed. You need to create a destructive change and deploy that first, or ensure you temporarily keep both the old and new API values with distinct labels (e.g. add " (OLD)" to the original API name labels).

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Thanks for the information. But even after renaming old API names(old) in target org and deploying new values, i am getting other duplicate label errors. Can you please suggest how to proceed in fixing these deployment errors?

Comment: Not only do you need to rename (API names) but you must also change the labels for these. Once you've done both you should be OK.

Comment: Yes yes, i have renamed old labels also Eg: Vascular Surgery to Vascular Surgery. (dot)

Comment: Hmmm. Strange. If the API names and labels are now different you shouldn't get conflicts. Double-check that you covered them all.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming API names sadly forces manual operations before a deployment, that's why teams must be told to avoid to do it when it is possible.

In case of rename, the simpler way it to manually rename items in the target org setup before deployment, to propagate the new values on existing records.